# what is linkage disequilibrium supposed to measure?

Tags: genetics

During reading about genetics I came across with the term of linkage disequilibrium, and I do not really understand what it supposed to mean. What is linkage disequilibrium? My current understanding that it is "deviation from independent assortment",

Comment: @Corvus - you were right, I totally mixed the two things..thx for pointing that out.  This is a good sign that I should go to sleep, I had a long day and its almost midnight.

Comment: @poka.nandor I know the feeling! Cheers.

Comment: Cagliari -- this is false. The **definition** of linkage  disequilibrium involves nonrandom association between alleles at different loci. One **cause** of linkage disequilibrium is physical linkage like you describe, but linkage disequilibrium can exist without physical linkage, Eg due to natural selection.

Answer (score 4):

Linkage disequilibrium refers to a situation whereby two or more alleles, from different loci, segregate non-randomly. Therefore we have a statistical association between this two alleles.
The linkage disequilibrium can be used in gene mapping, because we assume that these loci are in the same region on the chromosome. The more often they appear together, the more they segregate non-randomly, the closer they should be on the chromosome.

http://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_difference_between_Linkage_Equilibrium_and_Linkage_Disequilibrium